# Permitting nested arrays using strong params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I permit nested arrays using strong parameters?

```rb
ActionController::Parameters.new(filter: ['a', [1,2]]).permit(filter: [])
Unpermitted parameter: :filter
```

Expected output:

```rb
<ActionController::Parameters {"filter"=>["a", [1,2]]} permitted: true>
```

Comment: Can you please give us an example of the input parameters? And expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only way to work with nested parameters is to permit them as an array of hashes or use only scalar values inside the array.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an empty array:
>
> `params.permit(:id => [])`

> You can also use permit on nested parameters, like:
>
> `params.permit(:name, {:emails => []}, :friends => [ :name, { :family => [ :name ], :hobbies => [] }])`

Your case with flattened values:

```
> ActionController::Parameters.new(filter: ['a', 1,2]).permit(filter: [])
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"filter"=>["a", 1, 2]} permitted: true>
```

With an array of hashes:

```
> ActionController::Parameters.new(filter: [{param1: 'a', param2: [1,2]}]).permit(filter: [:param1, param2: []])
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"filter"=>[<ActionController::Parameters {"param1"=>"a", "param2"=>[1, 2]} permitted: true>]} permitted: true>
```